# Visual studio code auto refresh browser with apache

Tags: apache, visual-studio-code, refresh, local, auto

Is there a way to set up (extension, etc...) Visual studio code to auto-refresh browser (Firefox Dev, Chrome Dev) as soon as the file I am working on is saved? (Like Live Server extension)

I am working with local installation of Apache (Yes, I am working on WordPress :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wMmu_369n7c) tutorial from youtube you will install the *Live Server* VSCode extension for use with html files. However, you will most likely (although you haven't mentioned) be using PHP or other languages because apache supports it. For this, use [this](https://github.com/ritwickdey/live-server-web-extension/blob/master/docs/Setup.md) tutorial from GitHub. It installs a browser extension (compatible with chrome/chromium-based/firefox browsers) that connects to a server instance and serves the *reload* function to that webserver. This does *NOT* install a web server (in this case it shouldn't matter). If you follow the tutorial, it should be really self-explanatory.

Comment: Does this method support apache rewrites and other .htaccess rules? If not, it is useless to me (I mentioned I am working with WordPress).

Comment: As far as I know it should be supported. It worked for me and I have rewrites and .htaccess enabled on my server. Have you tried?

Comment: I ended using Live Reload extension for Firefox and Chrome. It works beautifully, it replaces css without reloading page